# How many strings of English letters contain exactly 3 z's and 3 w's with length 8?

Tags: combinatorics

since it is AND and not OR I figure after you find the number of strings that exactly contain 3 of each kind you simply square this number. I am just not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about squaring.  Suppose the string had length $6$ instead of length $8$.  Can you see that the answer would just be $\binom 63$?  Of course if the length were $5$ the answer to your question would be $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split into two mutually exclusive cases based on whether the 2 non z or w characters are the same or different.

If they are the same they can be chosen in $\binom{24}1 = 24$ ways
for each of these choices you can form $\frac {8!}{3!3!2!}=560$ distinct words.

If they are different they can be selected in $\binom{24}2=276$ ways

for each of these choices you can form $\frac {8!}{3!3!}=1120$ distinct words.

So the total number of distinct words is given by ...

$$ \begin{eqnarray} 
N_{tot} &=&\binom{24}1\frac {8!}{3!3!2!}+\binom{24}2 
\frac {8!}{3!3!}
 \\  &=& 24*560+276*1120
 \\&=&322560
  \end{eqnarray} $$

Answer (score 1):

The three $z$s can be placed in ${8 \choose 3}$ ways.  The three $w$s can then be placed in ${5 \choose 3}$ ways.  The remaining two slots can have $24$ letters in the first place and $24$ letters in the second place.

Multiply these:  $322560$.